# Position of div CSS

Tags: html, css

I am new in HTML and CSS. I have a problem with position of block under second block. Can you help me ? I need to make something like this.

The first block is on the left. The second is on the right, and under it are the third and fourth block. I used blocks in a line. How to make blocks 3 and 4 become lower under the second.

```css
.body {
  width: auto;
}

.box {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

.box-1 {
  background-color: rebeccapurple;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  float: left;
}

.box-2 {
  background-color: brown;
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  vertical-align: top;
  /* margin-left: 40px; */
}

.box-3 {
  background-color: chartreuse;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.box-4 {
  background-color: coral;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="section">
  <div class=" box box-1"></div>
  <div class=" box box-2"></div>
  <div class=" box box-3"></div>
  <div class=" box box-4"></div>
</div>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please post the code that you tries so far, and where did it fail.

Comment: @ItamarMushkin I've just added this. Can't send like text, stack overflow doesn't allow to do it

Comment: You're almost there: can you share where did your code fail? Error message, unexpected outcome, etc

Comment: @DavidThomas "so many code" - say StackOverflow :)

Comment: Please post your code _as text_. Not images. Read here: [MRE]

Comment: "So many codes" - You are getting this because you are adding codes only. Add some text where you explain your question in detail. Don't add pictures of codes as no one can test it.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than trying to position these elements with `float`, I'd suggest using CSS Grid layout:

```css
html, body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.section {
  /* using the CSS Grid layout: */
  display: grid;
  /* defining the named areas of the grid, using
     ASCII-art style layout: */
  grid-template-areas:
      "box1 box2 box2"
      "box1 box3 box4";
  /* defining the width of the three columns: */
  grid-template-columns: 300px 200px 200px;
  /* defining the height of the two rows: */
  grid-template-rows: 100px 200px;
  /* defining the gap between Grid items, note that this
     gutter - required to separate box-3 and box-4, for
     as an example, does require that that box-2 (above)
     has to be greater than 400px in width, due to the sum
     of widths + gutter-space: */
  grid-gap: 1em;
}

.box-1 {
  background-color: rebeccapurple;
  /* placing the element in the named grid-area: */
  grid-area: box1;
}

.box-2 {
  background-color: brown;
  grid-area: box2;
}

.box-3 {
  background-color: chartreuse;
  grid-area: box3;
}

.box-4 {
  background-color: coral;
  grid-area: box4;
}
```

```html
<div class="section">
  <div class=" box box-1"></div>
  <div class=" box box-2"></div>
  <div class=" box box-3"></div>
  <div class=" box box-4"></div>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/xouhc197/).

References:

- [`grid-area`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-area).
- [`grid-gap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-gap).
- [`grid-template-areas`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-areas).
- [`grid-template-columns`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-columns).
- [`grid-template-rows`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-rows).